What verb should be used in this sentence?
Here's the sentence:

He moved through the crowded avenue, ---- the throngs of people and avoiding the pickpockets.

Dodging and twisting seem somewhat suitable but not entirely, what verb should I use?
Note: Pushing is not applicable in the larger context.

Got the answer on further researching the internet. "Weaving through." Should I delete the post or is it of any use to anyone?

Edit
Other than the intransitive weaving as in weaving through suggested by the OP, we may consider its transitive use but with additional words. M+W sense 5 for weaving explains:

to direct (something, such as the body) in a winding or zigzag course especially to avoid obstacles

weaving my body through
the throngs of people ...
Another possible intransitive verb is  slaloming.  M+W has an example:

slalomed through the crowd with the ease of an Olympic skier

slaloming through
the throngs of people ...
